# Select three columns (A,B,C) and return rows where (B,C) are distinct and A is at max value because there are multiple occurrences of (B,C) pairs

Tags: sql, hive, max, distinct

Working in Hive, I have a table with three columns A(INT), B(STRING) and C(STRING). B & C columns have repeat paired values (ie row 1 & row 10 may have identical strings in columns B & C). I'm trying to return the full rows (ie A,B,C) of distinct B,C pairs where the A column is at it's max value among all occurrences of distinct B,C pairs. All help is appreciated.

Example of input table

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
----------------
1111, str1, str2 
2222, str1, str2
3333, str3, str4
4444, str5, str6
5555, str3, str4
6666, str5, str6
```

Example of output from query

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
----------------
2222, str1, str2
5555, str3, str4
6666, str5, str6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just the three columns in result:

```
select max(a) a, b, c
from your_table
group by b, c;
```

If you have more columns to select, you can use window function `row_number` for this:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by b, c
            order by a desc nulls last
            ) rn
    from your_table t
    ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: I used the first, simpler suggestion. Shrunk the table from 54M rows with repeats to 1.6M unique rows. 
The second suggestion returned NULLS. I check the input table and there are no NULLS in any columns. Thank you @GurV